# Visual Studio: Profiles for addins

Tags: visual-studio, profile, visual-studio-addins

I would like to be able to switch between using Visual Studio with C#-addins (Resharper, TestDriven.Net and VisualSVN) and C++-addins (Visual Assist X and VisualSVN). I have found that Resharper and Visual Assist X does not coexist very well and I would like an easy way to change between them.

Anyone know how to do that? If I can have different key-bindings for each profile, that would be a big plus - as would the ability to have different instances of Visual Studio running in different profiles.

Virtual machines would do it of course, but that seems overkill.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe to record two macros: one that starts the C# add-ins and stops the C++ add-ins, and the other doing the oposite? Then run one of the macros after starting IDE?

Answer (score 0):

Add .cs to the Extensions to ignore list in the VA Options dialog (Projects | File Handling) - but also report problems you are experiencing to [Whole Tomato](http://www.wholetomato.com/support/contact.asp)